# Which form of 'good' do I use?

Tags: наречия

Which is correct for saying that I am good (feeling) if someone says how are you? (Как ты):

- Я хорошо

or

- Я хорошая

Comment: what your research brought you so far?

Comment: @shabunc on google translate it seems both are correct, however, I dont know if one sounds better or not

Comment: Ethan, I have to close it since it's off-topic, it looks like you are not learning Russian, just want to translate a particular phrase. But well, you can go with "у меня всё хорошо" or "у меня всё нормально".

Comment: @shabunc oh im sorry! No i am learning, i am starting by learning conversations and in this conversation, I reply, "у меня всё хорошо." To say that I am feeling fine. After being asked how i am doing. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ethan, then, let me reopen this and sorry for the confusion. Somebody hopefully will give you a reference answer.

Comment: Ethan, I have witten a blog post (a while ago) that answers your exact question with a bit of background: http://russiangram.com/lessons/mne-horosho/

Comment: @SergeySlepov the answer supposed to be self-sufficient. Providing just link is not enough. Self-promoting without providing an answer here is also against rules.

Comment: <<мне хорошо>> или <<хорошо>> means "I am well" (more or less) while <<Я хорошая>> means "I am good," as in "I have the quality of goodness/I am a good person."

Answer (score 3):

The correct form would be

- Мне хорошо

Russian doesn't use the "be" verb for expressing emotional state, such as English or French. So, the adverb хорошо is correct grammatically. However, this expresses "I have a good feeling right now" and the answer is not the common to expect to this rather casual question. Usually, people would answer "All is good" or similar, i.e:

- Все хорошо (good)
- Все отлично (great)
- Все в порядке (in order)
- Все нормально (normal)

Comment: всё норм! всё зашибись!

Comment: Я хорошо is the right answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if "Мне хорошо" could be used here, it can mean something like "I have a pleasure right now".

Comment: Скорее "у меня все хорошо" или "я чувствую себя хорошо" if health condition is asked for. "Мне хорошо" is certainly about feeling pleasure

Comment: Yeah, "мне хорошо" outside of obviously pleasurable situation would be a bit off, and even may imply one is drunk ("он уже хороший" - "he is already drunk") or such. For a neutral "I'm ok" use rather a neutral "всё в порядке", "всё хорошо", "я в порядке", "я в норме" (the latter two if the question specifically asks about you, otherwise better to have a neutral generic answer). "я - хорошо" can be used too, if the question was specifically about your welfare/mood/etc.

Answer (score 2):

Я – хорошо́. Or just 'хорошо́':

- Как ты?
- Хорошо́!

This works for both men and women, no need to decline for gender

The reason we use an adverb here and not an adjective is because а verb is implied:

Я [живу́/чу́вствую себя́] хорошо́.
I [live/feel] well.

And a verb requires an adverb.

You can also say 'Всё хорошо́' (All good) or 'У меня́ всё хорошо́' (All good with me).

Comment: Never listen "Я хорошо", it sounds really bad. And we use adverb because "Как" was asked, it doesn't imply adjective as an answer, only adverb or full clause (often with adverb too)

Comment: @edo1: "Как ты?" - "Я хорошо́, а ты?" - sounds OK to me. Хорошо́ is an adverb here. It's just that the verb that is modifies (пожива́ю, чу́вствую себя́) is usually dropped.

Comment: "Я хорошо́, а ты?" is ok.  "Я — хорошо́" is ok too.  But not a clause "Я хорошо́".

Comment: edo1, agreed. Added the dash to my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Я хорошо - ungrammatical

Я хорошая - means "I am a good female person".

Comment: it is a wrong answer - "я хорошо" is rarely used but still used. Nothing ungrammatica about it.

Comment: @shabunc я хорошо is plainly wrong or incomplete sentence. Not even suitable as answer on a question.

Comment: What about "Как вы провели отпуск? - Я - хорошо, Андрей - плохо."

Comment: @Abakan obviously it has different punctuation.

Comment: Not obviously. It might have different pronunciation but does not have to. And there is no any particular pronunciation in written text!

Comment: @Abakan without punctuation it is ungrammatical

Comment: It has the correct punctuation and this is the right answer to the question.

Comment: "Я хорошо" definitely couldn't be used in russian (I'm native speaker)

Comment: But it could used in form "Я? Хорошо!" (sounds like you are not sure if question is about you), or "Я - хорошо, а вот Лёша плохо" (continuation is necessary).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "I am good." in English has many meanings. You are looking for the most modern of them. The Russian translations which you propose convey an earlier meaning.

Within the last two decades here in New English people have started to say "I am good." instead of "I am well", "I am fine." or even instead of "I do not need anything." Though the grammar is dubious, these expressions are understood. These meanings can be conveyed thus:

> У меня всё хорошо. (I am fine.)
>
> У меня всё в порядке. (I am OK, not hurt.)
>
> Ничего мне не надо. (I do not need anything.)

Earlier, in the late 20th century "I am good." was understood in line with its literal meaning: "good" described the quality of "I". A person who had just completed a feat of skill might boast "I am good!" Your suggestion "Я хорошая" ("I am a good.", spoken by a female) might be seen as an attempt to achieve this boasting meaning. "Я хорошо." also sounds like a boast, though it is missing a verb. Unless the context clearly supplies one, it must be included. For example, one could say "Я пою хорошо." ("I sing well.")

Still earlier, "I am good." meant "I am kind.", especially in 19th century novels. For example: "I am very good to you." would be "Я очень добр/добра к тебе."

Finally, "good" can refer to adherence to moral standards: "добродетельная женшина" (a good woman), or Eliza Dolittle's "It's a good girl I am!" (Я порядочная девушка!).

Comment: добр**о**детельная. And "Я хорошо" is ungrammatical as mentioned in another answer

Comment: @edo1 Sure "Я хорошо" is ungrammatical as an equational sentence. But here I am interpreting "хорошо" as an adverb meaning "well". I will try to clarify this.